# How to add numbers in the divs using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to add numbers inside the blocks after they are generated? Like first block says 1, second 2 and so on.  Here is my whole code currently. Just type in how many block you wish to generate in the input.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Traversering og elementskapelse</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Traversering og elemenskapelse</h1>     <!--Titles/text -->
    <p>Antall div'er å generere:
    <input id="numberInput" type="text" name="inputField" style=width:200px;>
    <input id="numberButton" type="button" onclick="BLOCKGENERATOR_APP.init();" value="Generer">
    </p>
    <section id="blockSection"></section>
    
    
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        
        
        // App-module pattern of main function
        var BLOCKGENERATOR_APP = {
            $blockSection: null,    //Divs
            blocks: null,           //Array
            
            init: function(){       //init
                var BG = BLOCKGENERATOR_APP;    //Shortens the code further
                var setSection = function(){    //Sets functions to html-section with id "blockSection"
                    BG.$blockSection = $("#blockSection");
                }();
                
                var spawnInput = function(){     //Initialize function for spawning the divs
                    var input = document.getElementById("numberInput").value;
                    BG.blocks = generator.fetchBlocks("div", input);                  
                    BG.$blockSection.append(BG.blocks);
                }();

                var setEvents = function(){         // Functions for div-interaction
                    $("div", BG.$blockSection).on("mouseenter", function() {    // When mouse touch div, the opacity renders to 1
                        $(this).animate({
                         opacity: 1.0   
                            }, 2000, function() {});                            // Set 2 sec transition time
                    });
                    
                    $("div", BG.$blockSection).on("click", function() {     // On click, color of targetet div will be changed to MediumOrchid
                        $(this).css("background-color", "MediumOrchid");
                    });
                    
                    $("div", BG.$blockSection).on("dblclick", function() {  // On double-click, color of targetet div will be changed to yellow
                        $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
                    });
                }();
            }//--end init
        };//--end BLOCKGENERATIR_APP
        
        
        // Function for generating divs \\
        var generator = (function(){                    
            var fetchBlocks = function(tag, input){
                var blocks = [];                        // Array of generated divs
                for(var i = 0; i < input; i++){         // Generates until input value is met
                    var $newBlock = $("<" + tag + ">")  //
                        .css(                           // Alters css properities of divs
                            {
                                "width": "80px",
                                "height": "80px",
                                "margin": "10px",
                                "background-color": "Red",
                                "float": "left",
                                "opacity": "0.5"        // Initial amount that's altered during event
                            }
                        );
                    blocks.push($newBlock);             // Adds instance of block to array
                }
                return blocks;                          // Returns array
            }//--end fetchBlocks
            
            return {fetchBlocks: fetchBlocks}           // Returns the blocks
        }());//--end generator
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which element do you consider a "box"? I searched for box in your code but couldn't find it.

Comment: block**.. my mistake!

anyway ameenulla0007's answer worked fine, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.text(i);` just add this after you apply css to the tags generated.. in your `generator` function..

something like this..

```
var $newBlock = $("<" + tag + ">").css({
        "width": "80px",
        "height": "80px",
        "margin": "10px",
        "background-color": "Red",
        "float": "left",
        "opacity": "0.5"
    }).text(i);
```